# CPLEX Error 1001: Out of memory

Tags: java, linux

I was trying to solve an LP with CPLEX.
It throws an exception "CPLEX Error  1001: Out of memory" when I am building the model.
Please note that I am getting this error while modelling and not while optimizing.
There are google results for  Out of memory scenarios during optimization.

Your help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the response.
The issue is temporarily solved.

I was running the optimizer on a server with 8G ram (3G free) and the model was huge.
We have been starting JRE with Min Heap size ( `java -Xms1G` ) set to 1G. I believe this caused JRE to reserve a lot of space in the server memory; leaving no room for the CPLEX process.

After numerous trial and error experiments with different CPLEX parameters (all of them failed!), we attempted start the optimizer with `java -Xms512M -Xmx750M` and it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's very little information to work with here... does the problem occur for small LPs? How big of an LP are you building? Have you seen this [ILOG forum thread](http://forums.ilog.com/optimization/index.php?action=printpage;topic=556.0)?

Answer (score 0):

call the end methods of the objects e.g. csvreader, iterator, cplex, environment that you have creaed. that will free up the memory and resolve this issue.